# PHP - Long polling, session gets destroyed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, long-polling

I am trying for the first time to use long polling in order to update my users messages list in real time, websockets seem too complicated for me. My application runs in local for now.

Here is the PHP code, it's not complete, I am just making tests so far :

```js
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    ignore_user_abort(false);

    $isUptodate = (bool) file_get_contents($this->uptodateFile);

    while ($isUptodate === true)
    {
      sleep(1);
      $isUptodate = (bool) file_get_contents($this->uptodateFile);
    }

    $updateUptodateFile = fopen($this->uptodateFile, 'w');
    fwrite($updateUptodateFile, 'true');

    $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->updateFile), true);

    echo json_encode(['updates' => count($jsonData)]);
```

And here is the JS code (again, these are tries, the setTimeout delays will be changed later when code is working fine) :

```js
    checkForUpdates: function ()
    {
      var that = this;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'updates.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 10000
      }).done(function (data)
      {
        console.log('data received');
        if (data.updates)
        {
          alert('nouveau message');
          setTimeout(function () { that.checkForUpdates() }, 5000);
        }
      }).fail(function (data)
      {
        console.log(data);
        setTimeout(function () { that.checkForUpdates() }, 10000);
      });
    }
```

So, first weird thing is that, if I set `async: true, cache: false` in ajax parameters, the code won't properly load my updates.php file.

Second strange thing to me, is that if my loop runs for a certain amount of time, my session gets destroyed.

Why? About long polling, am I doing this right?

Comment: As an alternative to long-polling (and not using WebSockets if you don't like those) you could have a read abou PHP Server-Side Events:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: @Ezenhis thanks, this is interesting. Though it seems that Edge and IE are not supporting this, and I need a simple cross-browser solution... But I'll keep server-side events in mind.